# Unable to view linkedin button image when using the LinkedIn module with Play

Tags: playframework, linkedin-api

The LinkedIn button image evaluates to the foll
http://developer.linkedin.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/102-1182-2-1070/152-21/log-in-linkedin-small.png

which results in not found!!
Is there an updated module which addresses this?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I can work on that or you can update the link on https://github.com/feliperazeek/playframework-linkedin and issue a pull request.

Comment: Have not done that before. Will do that and then update you. Thanks